# UWP ScrollViewer and StackPanels don't work properly

Tags: c#, uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

The UWP `ScrollViewer` element isn't scrolling at all with my `StackPanel`. I've tried `Grid`s and the row definitions but that didn't work either. Here is my current XAML.

[GIF showing scrolling not working properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9PFj.gif)

```
<Page
    x:Class="Thunderstorm.Pages.Home"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Thunderstorm.Pages"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <StackPanel>
            <StackPanel x:Name="Weather"
                        Background="LightBlue"
                        Height="500"
                        MaxHeight="750"
                        VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                        Padding="10,0,0,0">
                <TextBlock Text="25℉" Style="{ThemeResource HeaderTextBlockStyle}" FontSize="85" Margin="25,25,0,0" MaxWidth="500" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="Scroll test string to overflow"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Scroll test string to overflow"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Scroll test string to overflow"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Scroll test string to overflow"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Scroll test string to overflow"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Scroll test string to overflow"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Scroll test string to overflow"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Scroll test string to overflow"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Scroll test string to overflow"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Scroll test string to overflow"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Scroll test string to overflow"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Scroll test string to overflow"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Scroll test string to overflow"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Scroll test string to overflow"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Scroll test string to overflow"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Scroll test string to overflow"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Scroll test string to overflow"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Scroll test string to overflow"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Page>
```

(I apologize if this is a stupid question - I'm new to UWP development, also disregard me explicitly defining font size on the `TextBlock`)

Comment: `Isn't working properly`,please explain this term

Comment: @zackraiyan it doesn't scroll properly, sorry. i'll edit it

Comment: try to provide a gif to show what is really happening

Comment: Does the scrollbar appear ?

Comment: @zackraiyan scroll bar does appear when I set the `VerticalScrollBarVisibility` to `Visible`, it was set to `Auto` and it won't show.

Comment: Add a grid inside the scrollviewer , resize it so that it overflows the scrollviewer,then inside the grid add your stackpanel ... Hope it works :)

Comment: and remove `verticalScrollbarVisibility`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The frame I was calling navigate on was inside of a stackpanel and I never noticed it until now. I removed the stackpanel and scrolling worked with my original code.

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to reproduce your problem, not even when I place the page in a navigation view as in the GIF example.

I suspect, that there is a parent element that is allowing the content to grow to any size possible. You can test this yourself in a blank project. When you put the XAML you posted in a blank project, the scrolling will work as expected.

When you put the `ScrollViewer` in a `StackPanel` or `Grid` with `RowHeight="Auto"`, it will not scroll, as the parent "offered" it any space it requires. And the GIF actually proves that - see that the scrollviewer's bottom is cropped (the arrow down is not visible) - that is because something up the hierarchy is letting it to grow to any size it wants.

Does the `ScrollViewer` have any parent? And if not, how do you display the page in the `NavigationView`? If my suggestion does not help, please post the `NavigationView` XAML as well.

Comment: I am using the Microsoft UWP Community Toolkit's HamburgerMenu with the `UseNavigationViewWhenPossible` option set to true. I have a `Frame` that I am calling navigate on with `typeof(Pages.Home)`.

Comment: In that case it is very weird... Could you possibly create a simple GitHub repo that I could try out myself to be able to replicate the problem? It is enough if it contains just the bare minimum required to demonstrate the problem

Comment: Yes, one second